# obtain downloaded file path from WebBrowser component

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Using the `WebBrowser` component in C#, is it possible to obtain the file path of a user downloaded file?

For example, a user is browsing an arbitrary website using the `WebBrowser` then clicks a link to download, say, a PDF. The default download manager pops-up and prompts the user to save the file and the user can download the file to a location of their choice; but I do not know where they have saved that file.

Is this actually possible using the `WebBrowser` control?

Comment: I think you might need a [Custom Download Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753618(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender,
    WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    client.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadDataCompleted);

    client.DownloadDataAsync(e.Url);
}

void client_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = textBox1.Text;
    File.WriteAllBytes(filepath, e.Result);
    MessageBox.Show("File downloaded");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't handle if a user right clicks on an image and downloads via "save image as..."

Answer (score 0):

When you host the web browser component, you can handle all the events. So for example, you can handle the right click, override the menu and  show your custom menu.

So When the user clicks on a link or right clicks, you can show your own dialog instead of the system dialog and then you can have the path of the downloaded file from your own dialog.

Comment: I don't suppose you have a small example to get me going, do you?